# iOS: new image on LaunchScreen.storyboard not showing updating app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

this is my problem.

I have an app with version v1.0.0. I have built a splash screen from Storyboard, its name is **LaunchScreen.storyboard** and it has three elements: a background image, **a header image** and a footer image. In the General Settings into the Project, in "App Icons and Launch Images" section, in subsection "Launch Screen File" is set like "LaunchScreen". it works perfect!

Well, in this new version (v1.1.0) I had to replace the first image of header image for another one in png. So, when I simulate the update app process (Run app v1.0.0, then run app v1.1.0), and every element show but header image not. If I uninstall the v1.0.0 app and install app v1.1.0 is not showing the new image. The only way that I can see the new image in app update process is if I refresh the device (long press Home button + Power Button until restart device) and install directly the version v1.1.0.

I need to show this new header image in that app update process. Anyone have idea or a solution for that? or if is a bug of iOS anyone know the oficial reference to justify this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you even find any solution or did you get a reply?

Comment: The only reply that I found is this is a Xcode's bug. Let me try to replicate it again because when I reported this problem I was working in Xcode 9. I don't know if it was fixed.

Comment: It is not fixed yet. I am still seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same behavior in Xcode 8.2.1:  After editing a subImage superimposed on a launchScreen storyboard, the modified subImage does not get reflected in subsequent app runs, either in the sim or on a physical device.
Rebooting the sim sometimes works, sometimes I have to delete the subImage, rename it (because just re adding it in Interface Builder does not do the trick) and then replace it with IB.

I chalk this up to an Xcode bug.

Comment: is it correct. I have write to Apple explain this problema and the answer me that it could be a SDK or iOS bug, and I made a report.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a cached image for which the rules regarding flushing that cache are not disclosed. It would be very nice the system would recognize that the data changed and a new image should be cached. This applies to be sim and to physical devices.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer